# 'dask.dataframe' has no attribute 'read_sql_query'

Tags: python, sql, dask, dask-dataframe

I have tried multiple things like example: `pip install "dask[complete]"`. Probably every possible solution mentioned on stackoverflow or any other website but I still get these nonsense errors

> Query could not be executed due to module 'dask.dataframe' has no attribute 'read_sql'
> Or
> Query could not be executed due to module 'dask.dataframe' has no attribute 'read_sql_query'

My code snippet:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(user=username,
                                    password=pwd,
                                    host=host,
                                    port=port,
                                    database=database)

data = dd.read_sql(dml, conn,"SampleId")
```

Please let me know what further can be done with it!

Comment: Hi there, I understand your frustration. I was able to reproduce this with dask=2022.1.0, and I was able to fix it by upgrading to dask=2022.3.0. I hope this helps. If not, could you please share the versions of python and dask you're using?

Comment: Note that you should NOT pass a connection object, but a connection string as defined by sqlalchemy